# Using Nested Select from different table to form a condition

Tags: mysql

I'm using the lahman sabermetrics database to learn MySQL

I'm trying to see which pitchers have the highest total Home Runs across the data. The batting table contains the Home Runs (HR) column, whereas the fielding table contains the Position column (POS)

I've tried the following

```
SELECT playerID, SUM(HR) AS HR_SUM_TOTAL
FROM batting
GROUP BY playerID
WHERE (SELECT POS
       FROM fielding
       WHERE POS = "P")
ORDER BY HR_SUM_TOTAL DESC
```

Is there any way I can do that with a nested select or would it be easier to just add the POS column to the batting table and then run the query?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what's the issue? what doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly one way to do it would be

```sql
SELECT b.playerID, SUM(b.HR) HR_SUM_TOTAL
  FROM batting b JOIN 
  (
      SELECT DISTINCT playerID
        FROM fielding
       WHERE POS = 'P'
  ) f ON b.playerID = f.playerID
 GROUP BY b.playerID
 ORDER BY HR_SUM_TOTAL DESC
```

or

```sql
SELECT playerID, SUM(HR) HR_SUM_TOTAL
  FROM batting 
 WHERE playerID IN
 (
     SELECT DISTINCT playerID
       FROM fielding
      WHERE POS = 'P'
 )
 GROUP BY playerID
 ORDER BY HR_SUM_TOTAL DESC
```

Comment: I haven´t learned how to JOIN tables yet so I guess that´s way I was having trouble doing that.

Comment: You're very welcome :). See the updated answer for a version without `JOIN`